# Import MATLAB algorithm into an Android device

Tags: android, matlab, opencv, design-patterns, feature-detection

First, sorry for my poor english. Ok, I would like to implement an algorithm into an android device. My goal is to detect an hexagon pattern in an image/photo which is take directly on the android.

I've seen that it seems to be more easily to develop those kind of algorithm on Matlab which I think is appropriate to this image processing.

So here comes my question : If I got a Matlab code which can recognize my patterns in a photo, can I import them into my android device application ?

I've heard about .jar importation and openCV (Hough Transform), i've try the last one and it seems easy to recognize circle or square but I need to recognize more complicated pattern as hexagon are (?).

Thank you in advance,
J.

Comment: Matlab code importing is not possible. Always check for memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rewrite the matlab code (either to Java or to C++ native code).